# Select rows based on a combination of matched and not matched columns

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have a table like this one:

```
 data <- data.frame(a = c("0/0", "0/1", "0/0", "0/0" ),
                    b = c("0/1", "./.", "0/1", "0/0"),
                    c = c("1/0", "0/0", "1/1", "0/0"),
                    d = c("1/0", "0/0", "1/1", "0/0"),                       
                    f = c("L", "L", "T", "L"))
```

I would like to select any row that contains at least one 0/1 or 1/0 and no ./. in the columns a, b and c, and that match L in the column f.

I am trying this using the library *data.table*

```
data[data$a %like% "0/1|1/0" | data$b %like% "0/1|1/0"| data$c %like% "0/1|1/0" & !(data$a %like% "./.") & !(data$b %like% "./.") & !(data$c %like% "./.") & data$f == "L", ]
```

But it is not working.

The table looks like this:

```
       a   b   c   d   f
    1 0/0 0/1 1/0 1/0  L
    2 0/1 ./. 0/0 0/0  L
    3 0/0 0/1 1/1 1/1  T
    4 0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0  L
```

And the desired output should look like this:

```
       a   b   c   d   f
    1 0/0 0/1 1/0 1/0  L
```

Do you know how I could achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data[ apply(sapply(data[1:4], `%in%`, c('0/1','1/0')), 1, any) &
      apply(sapply(data[1:3], Negate(`%in%`), c('./.')), 1, all) &
      data$f == "L", ]
#     a   b   c   d f
# 1 0/0 0/1 1/0 1/0 L
```

Broken down:

```
sapply(data[1:4], `%in%`, c('0/1','1/0'))
#          a     b     c     d
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

That gives us the instances in the first four columns with one of the two "wanted" patterns. We want rows where *any* of the columns have it, so we "any" across them:

```
apply(sapply(data[1:4], `%in%`, c('0/1','1/0')), 1, any)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Similarly, find those with the "not wanted" patterns:

```
sapply(data[1:3], Negate(`%in%`), c('./.'))
#         a     b    c
# [1,] TRUE  TRUE TRUE
# [2,] TRUE FALSE TRUE
# [3,] TRUE  TRUE TRUE
# [4,] TRUE  TRUE TRUE
apply(sapply(data[1:3], Negate(`%in%`), c('./.')), 1, all) # notice "all", not "any"
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Now we want "L" in the last column (`=="L"`), straight-forward to chain them logically with `&`.

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means faster than a working data.table solution but this works with base R:

```
dat <- data.frame(a = c("0/0", "0/1", "0/0", "0/0" ),
                   b = c("0/1", "./.", "0/1", "0/0"),
                   c = c("1/0", "0/0", "1/1", "0/0"),
                   d = c("1/0", "0/0", "1/1", "0/0"),                       
                   f = c("L", "L", "T", "L"))

dat
f <- which(colnames(dat) == 'f')
rows <- apply(dat, 1, function(x)  x[f] == "L" & !any("./." == x[-f]) & any("0/1" == x[-f]) | any("1/0" == x[-f]) )
dat[rows,]
```

It uses the apply function to apply a function by row on the data.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the previous answer:

```
apply(data[, 1:4], 1, function(a) any(a %in% c("0/1","1/0")) && !any(a[1:3] == "./.")) & data$f == "L"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
data[f=="L", .SD[apply((.SD=="1/0" | .SD=="0/1") & !apply(.SD=="./.",1,any), 1, any)], 
    .SDcols=c("a","b","c","d")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using `apply` from base R -

```
test <- apply(data, 1, function(x) {
  any(x %in% c("0/1", "1/0")) & !any(x == "./.") & x["f"] == "L"
})

data[test, ]

#     a   b   c   d f
# 1 0/0 0/1 1/0 1/0 L
```

Comment: This would not work as expected if there was e.g. "0/1" in `f` or "./." in `d`.

Answer (score 0):

You can first concatenate the columns `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` together.

```
data[, abcd := paste(a, b, c, d)]
```

Then, I would create another new column which will tell me whether the conditions are met. I first set it to all `FALSE`.

```
data[, Selection := F]
```

Next, only for the columns that meet the conditions are being assigned `TRUE`.

(1) having `"0/1"` or `"1/0"` in `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d`, or simply `abcd`

(2) not having `"./."` in `abcd`

(3) having `"L"` in column `f`

```
data[(grepl("0/1", abcd) | grepl("1/0", abcd)) & !grepl("\\./\\.", abcd) &
     f == "L",
     Selection := T]
```

From here, I can select the row(s) needed by

```
data[(Selection), ]
```